# Excel tricky formula

Tags: excel

$h$5 holds a date in mm/dd/yyyy format

C4 holds a date of incident

D4 holds date rolled off

E4 holds a number value. Usually 1.

In h5, I put a date of write up. I'm trying to make a formula for d4. I want d4 to show a date when it will roll off. However, if h5 has a date less than or equal to 90 days, it won't roll off until after the 90 days.

The rule I'm trying to resolve is this:

An occurrence rolls off after one year. In c4, if it is less than a year, then d4 needs to show the date one year from c4 UNTIL it rolls off one year later which it can say rolled off.

If BEFORE it rolls off, there is a write up date in h5, the rolled off can't show until after the 90 day freeze.

My trouble happens if it is after the date, I can't get it to show rolled off. What works if no date in h5 is..

=IF(C4="","",IF($H$5<>"",DATE(YEAR(C4)+1,MONTH(C4),DAY(C4)),IF($H$5>=TODAY()-90,DATE(YEAR(C4)+1,MONTH(C4),DAY(C4)),IF(DATE(YEAR(C4)+1,MONTH(C4),DAY(C4))>TODAY(),(DATE(YEAR(C4)+1,MONTH(C4),DAY(C4))),IF(C4="","","Rolled Off")))))

Once a day goes in h5, it does the wrong thing.

Help.

____________edit_____________

Today is 12/30/2014.

Date of Incident (C)  Date of Roll Off     (D)

12/31/2013              12/31/2014

12/2/2013               Rolled Off

12/3/2013               Rolled Off

12/4/2013               Rolled Off

12/5/2013               Rolled Off

12/1/2013               Rolled Off

H5   _____

If H5 Date is blank, it shows what is above. See how 12/31/2014 has not arrived yet, but 12/2/2013, would have made 12/2/2014 which has passed because it has been a year. So fine, a simple formula with an if statement would suffice to make it say make this date or put Rolled Off.

The confusion comes because I have cell H5 that is a variable cell. If it has a date in it, I need this to happen…

If the user types in today’s date in H5, (12/30/2014), then anything that would have “rolled off” from 12/30 through 90 days after (3/31/2015), needs to still hold the same date. So in this example, I still need 12/1 – 12/5/13 to still say “Rolled off.” Fine, easy. However, tomorrow, I still need 12/31/13 to still show 12/31/2014 in the next cell until the 90 day probation rolls off from the date in Cell H5.

To explain in a non-excel way, it is like this. If you miss work, you get an occurrence (a ding) so you type the date on this spreadsheet and it tells you in a year it will roll off. By the time the year comes, it will say “Rolled Off.” If you happen to get too many occurrences, at my job, you will get a write up. So you would put the date of that write up in cell H5. At my job, if you get a write up, it locks any time that would have rolled off 90 days after your write-up as kind of a punishment. After the 90 days, the things that would come off are able to be wiped clean. So in this example the date above would not come off 12/31/14 (tomorrow), it would come off 3/31/2015. Had I not received a write up, it would have come off 12/31.

I hope this helps.

Comment: E4 has nothing to do with this section.

Comment: H5 is a date of getting a write up. So after missing too many days, the date placed in h5 is the date you signed the paper. So 90 days into the future from the h5 date.

Comment: During the 90 days, if one of the days roll off, it is null until after the 90 days

Comment: @traveler84 pnuts' comment is curt, but he isn't wrong. You have failed to provide a concise list of rules you are trying to codify into a formula. Try providing (as an edit to your question) some examples. i.e. what if c4 is x date, and h5 is y date, then what would you expect the date in d4 to be. Use examples that would show the normal case and outliers.

Comment: @traveler84 worry about fixing the question. The votes tend to follow. Not great practice to ask for people to change their votes.

Comment: @traveler84 Can you please chenge the title to something that is more helpful? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood what you're asking, I believe the formula you're looking for in cell D4 and copied down is:

```
=IF(C4="","",IF(OR(C4+365>TODAY(),AND($H$5>0,C4+365>=$H$5,C4+365<$H$5+90)),C4+365,"Rolled Off"))
```

If you would prefer to use `DATE(YEAR(C4)+1,MONTH(C4),DAY(C4))` instead of `C4+365` that is fine, just replace all instances of `C4+365` with the `DATE(...)` function.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. This past the battery off test I executed. I see you used the or statement. The or included an option with an and statement. That makes so much sense to give the and statement to say if ask the variables are met or if the other option is met. I've been trying to figure this out for weeks and the longer the nested statement, the more confused I became. Oh and I'll use your short hand 365 + c4. Lol. Anyhow, I learned something new. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for.

```
=IF($H$5="",IF(C4>DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),C4,"Rolled Off"),IF(C4>DATE(YEAR($H$5)-1,MONTH($H$5),DAY($H$5)-90),C4,"Rolled Off"))
```

The logic follows these steps:

```
1. If H5 is empty, then
    a. If incident date is greater than today less 1 year ==> return incident date
    b. Otherwise ==> return "Rolled Off"
2. If H5 is not empty, then
    a. If incident date is greater than H5 less 1 year and 90 days ==> return incident date
    b. Otherwise ==> return "Rolled Off"
```

Comment: Thank you. With a little refining I could have made it work but tiger's was spot on. I tested yours first but it was not doing exactly as needed.